# After upgrading to 12.04, my screen resolution is small

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, resolution

I just upgraded Ubuntu to 12.04 from 11.10.  My screen resolution is now stuck at 640x480, and xrandr shows:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 640 x 480, maximum 8192 x 8192
DVI-I-1 connected 640x480+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 376mm x 301mm
   640x480        60.0* 
   720x400        70.1
```

I normally have a much higher screen resolution.

I have an Nvidia video card, and I  had the restricted drivers installed before the upgrade.  When I attempt to install Additional Drivers, I see this dialog, which doesn't seem right:

[image: Additional Drivers]

Also when I type "jockey-text --list", I get nothing.

What might have gone wrong, and how I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to open Restricted Drivers again, what would you see?

If all else fails, It may be worth to reinstall Ubuntu, however this may not be a option for you.

Comment: I didn't want to have to do it, but reinstalling fixed the issue.